# Grep function and regular expression to find out the right col names

Tags: r, regex

I have tried so many different expressions but none seem to work, so here I am..

> 

I was trying to pick the col names that does not contain Margin nor Rate nor YoY.
Below is the data set.

```
  colnames(IS.nodes)
 [1] "Revenue"                      "Revenue Growth (YoY)"        
 [3] "Cost of Revenue"              "Gross Profit"                
 [5] "Selling, General & Admin"     "Research & Development"      
 [7] "Operating Expenses"           "Operating Income"            
 [9] "Other Expense / Income"       "Pretax Income"               
[11] "Income Tax"                   "Net Income"                  
[13] "Shares Outstanding (Basic)"   "Shares Outstanding (Diluted)"
[15] "Shares Change (YoY)"          "EPS (Basic)"                 
[17] "EPS (Diluted)"                "EPS Growth (YoY)"
[18] "EBITDA Margin"                "EBIT Margin"
[19] "Effective Tax Rate"
```

End result should contain the col names that don't have any word "margin" or "rate" or "YoY"

```
grep(c("[^Margin]|[^Rate]|[^YoY]"),colnames(IS.nodes),value=T)
```

but this doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `invert = TRUE` argument in `grep`.  So, instead of `^` inside the square bracket (but it will be only to match the characters and not the word).  If we want to also remove those having different case, use `ignore.case = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`)

```
out <- IS.nodes[grep("Margin|Rate|YoY", colnames(IS.nodes), 
      value = TRUE, invert = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)]

names(out)
#[1] "Revenue"                      "Cost of Revenue"              "Gross Profit"                 "Selling, General & Admin"    
#[5] "Research & Development"       "Operating Expenses"           "Operating Income"             "Other Expense / Income"      
#[9] "Pretax Income"                "Income Tax"                   "Net Income"                   "Shares Outstanding (Basic)"  
#[13] "Shares Outstanding (Diluted)" "EPS (Basic)"                  "EPS (Diluted)"
```

---

When we do the `pattern` as

```
[^Margin]
```

It is looking for all characters other than the uppercase M, a, r, g, i, and n and it is not suggesting not to match "Margin", though it is one of the many combinations of those letters

#### data

```
IS.nodes <- structure(list(Revenue = c(63L, 66L, 51L, 29L), `Revenue Growth (YoY)` = c(41L, 
11L, 59L, 54L), `Cost of Revenue` = c(12L, 49L, 69L, 64L), `Gross Profit` = c(42L, 
15L, 18L, 77L), `Selling, General & Admin` = c(75L, 2L, 1L, 68L
), `Research & Development` = c(26L, 74L, 56L, 57L), `Operating Expenses` = c(44L, 
65L, 81L, 62L), `Operating Income` = c(47L, 83L, 9L, 78L), `Other Expense / Income` = c(53L, 
82L, 43L, 45L), `Pretax Income` = c(10L, 48L, 52L, 21L), `Income Tax` = c(30L, 
20L, 71L, 34L), `Net Income` = c(79L, 6L, 39L, 35L), `Shares Outstanding (Basic)` = c(31L, 
61L, 38L, 5L), `Shares Outstanding (Diluted)` = c(8L, 16L, 22L, 
50L), `Shares Change (YoY)` = c(67L, 28L, 4L, 36L), `EPS (Basic)` = c(37L, 
58L, 84L, 25L), `EPS (Diluted)` = c(14L, 72L, 55L, 70L), `EPS Growth (YoY)` = c(40L, 
23L, 33L, 24L), `EBITDA Margin` = c(76L, 19L, 27L, 13L), `EBIT Margin` = c(32L, 
73L, 17L, 60L), `Effective Tax Rate` = c(7L, 46L, 3L, 80L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```